# forward UDP packets to different IP with scapy

Tags: ip, scapy, packet, forward, spoof

I want to send the captured packets to another PC in my local network.
When I run it I keep getting the Output:

```
Sent 1 packets.
```

Over and over, but in Wireshark I dont see any packets going to the IP-Adress 192.168.0.5...
Not sure what is wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from scapy.all import sniff, send

def spoof_and_send(packet):
    packet[0][1].dst = '192.168.0.5'
    send(packet)

packets = sniff(filter='udp and portrange 6000-7999', prn=spoof_and_send)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the original Ethernet header:

```
def spoof_and_send(packet):
    datagram = packet[IP]
    datagram.dst = "192.168.0.5"
    send(packet)
```

Moreover, if you use this code you are going to receive the packets you create. You need to filter those out to avoid loops.